# Ruby on Rails: Running custom validation function only when other properties are present

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord, rspec-rails

I want my custom validator to only run when the properties it uses are present.

```
# these are all dates
validates :start_time, presence: true
validates :end_time, presence: true
validates :deadline_visitor, presence: true
validates :deadline_host, presence: true

# these validate the above dates
validate :validate_all_dates
validate :validate_dates
```

example:

```
def validate_all_dates
  if self.start_time > self.end_time
    errors.add(:start_time, 'must be before or the same day as end time')
  end
end
```

fails because `self.start_time` and `self.end_time` are not present

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add an `if` parameter to the `validate` method, this can check the conditions needed. That parameter can take either be a proc:

```
validates :validate_all_dates, if: Proc.new { |model| model.start_time.presence }
```

Or with a method:

```
validate :validate_all_dates, if: :dates_present?

def dates_present?
  start_time.presence && end_time.presence
end
```

Take a look at this guide for more details: [Conditional Validation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#conditional-validation)

Answer (score 1):

You can add the presence of the variables in the validator itself:

```
def validate_all_dates
  if self.start_time && self.end_time && self.start_time > self.end_time
    errors.add(:start_time, 'must be before or the same day as end     time')
  end
end
```